# Data interpolation using Range.DataSeries [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation, series

I have some date based data that I'm trying to interpolate between (horizontally). See image below, I found some code on a similar answer however when I've adapted it, it isn't interpolating. I also have start and end points for each row which are equal to 0. e.g. Row 3, Sept 15.

Where am I going wrong with this?

```
Sub interpolateData()
Dim rng As Range

With Sheets("Timeline")

    Set rng = .Cells(8, 4)
    Do While CBool(Application.CountIf(.Rows(8), 0))
        With .Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
                .DataSeries rowCol:=xlRows, Type:=xlLinear, _
                    Step:=(.Cells(.Cells.Count).Value2 - .Cells(1).Value2) / (.Columns.Count - 1)
        End With
        Set rng = .Cells(8, 4).End(xlToRight)
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Let me guess - you enter an endless loop on the first row that you work with? That is because of this -  `Set rng = .Cells(8, 4).End(xlToRight)` Probably instead you should set the `rng` to the next row.  `Set rng = .Cells(rng.row+2, 4)` or something similar.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, and it no longer runs infinitely, however zeros each row whereas I want it to interpolate between points.

Comment: Then start using F8 and debug to see what is going wrong. :) And compare with the idea of Microsoft - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214096/method-to-calculate-interpolation-step-value-in-excel

Comment: I couldn't get that way to work, so I ended up creating a macro that found the data point column positions and using the equation of the line, calculated the value for each cell inbetween. It runs quick enough so I'm happy with that solution and it gives me more parameters to play around with. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Welcome :) The idea of F8 is that it goes step by step, thus it is easy to debug and to understand what is happening.